# Spring Bean Session Scope for currentUser

Tags: spring, session, authentication, scope

I just recently started working with Spring at college and therefore I'm still quite lost. At the moment we're trying to write an application that will pretty much copy doodle.

We have managed to build a login.jsp that actually verifies the login against our h2-database and then redirects to the list of all available polls. Now we want to be able to get the currentUser from the session scope to show on the top right and also use for further actions as well as to sign of the user.

So far I have edited my spring-config.xml with:

```
    <!-- Session Scope -->
<bean id="userInfo" class="de.nordakademie.iaa.nakdate.sessionbeans.UserInfo" scope="session">
</bean>
```

Then I have put this

```
<p align="right">%{#userInfo.username}</p>
```

into the header.jsp, which will be visible on every page even the first page without an user logged in. Is that a smart way of doing it? And might it work even?

Last I made an UserInfo.java as follwing:

```
package de.nordakademie.iaa.nakdate.sessionbeans;

public class UserInfo {
public String username;

public UserInfo(){
    this.username = "Unregistered User";
}
```

}

I will also publish our Login action here:

```
package de.nordakademie.iaa.nakdate.action;

import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import de.nordakademie.iaa.nakdate.model.User;
import de.nordakademie.iaa.nakdate.service.UserService;

public class LogInUserAction extends ActionSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3734334931859908102L;
private transient UserService userService;
private transient User user;
private String email;
private String password;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    List<User> users = userService.loadAll();
    for (User currentUser : users) {
        if (currentUser.getEmail().equals(getEmail())) {
            if (currentUser.getPassword().equals(getPassword())) {
                return SUCCESS;
            }
        }
    }
    addActionError(getText("E-Mail / Passwort falsch!"));
    return ERROR;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public UserService getUserService() {
    return userService;
}

public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

I would appreciate if anyone could help out on how to get this working. Thank you very much!

EDIT:
I have just used the debug tag and found out that my session is empty. What do I need to do to actually fill something into the session?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I can think of:
The first is to add a model attribute and access the model attribute in the jsp, this way:

In your Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @Autowired Userinfo userInfo;

    @RequestMapping
    public String myMethod(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userInfo", userInfo);
        ....
    }
```

Then you can refer to this in jsp:

```
${userInfo.name}
```

The second way, unfortunately not a documented approach is to refer to the scoped bean this way:

```
${sessionScope['scopedTarget.userInfo'].name}
```

This is from here: http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/11/01/accessing-spring-session-beans-in-jsp/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by controller. I do have a UserServiceImpl and an UserAction. Where exactly do I put a controller?

Comment: Oh, I thought you are using Spring-MVC, I now see that you are not using Spring MVC - you can then use the second approach of referring to it using `${sessionScope['scopedTarget.userInfo'].name}`

Comment: OK, I have tried that in my jsp, but the tag is not there. With the debug tag I can see that my session is empty. What do I need to do, to fill my session?

Comment: Try adding a `org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter` in web.xml as a filter or probably a better one - add this listener in web.xml - `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener`